# Child Component to wait for Parent Component ngOnInit async operation before initializing

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, mat-stepper

I'm using `mat-stepper` for implementing customer onboarding process. 
All 5 individual `child` `mat-stepper` `component` are inside one `parent` component.

```
<parent-html>
   <mat-horizontal-stepper #ccStepper [linear]="isLinear">
     <mat-step [stepControl]="childAForm">
       <child-a></child-a>
     </mat-step>
   </mat-horizontal-stepper>

 <mat-horizontal-stepper #ccStepper [linear]="isLinear">
     <mat-step [stepControl]="childBForm">
       <child-b></child-b>
     </mat-step>
   </mat-horizontal-stepper>
//3 more child components
</parent-html>
```

I have to `save and proceed` data for each child component. `applicationID` is generated after `save and proceed` of `first child` component and my `second`, `third` and `fourth` child components have to persist data entered in `first` component based on `applicationID`.

To further complicate things, whenever user saves information, it has to be stored as `draft` with `applicationID` generated (different route altogether). User can then click on `applicationID` and all the same information have to be fetched and user can then edit the information of previous and next component.

For normal save and proceed, I am storing `applicationID` in `behaviour subject` and fetching all the information in all child components.

Is it the right way to do as it triggers multiple calls even though I have information available in sibling components?

For edit scenario, I am passing the customer information via `@Input` to all child components. The problem here is `child` `ngOnInit` is fired before `parent` `ngOnInit` has resolved the `@Input` value. hence always failing the condition check.

What would be the best approach to solve it? Thanks for your time!!!

Answer (score 0):

For Edit Scenario, If you pass value using @Input decorator from Parent to Child Component. You can access those values using ngOnChanges() method in child component.

Child Component:

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(this.inputData){}
}
```

For Application ID, you can set the application ID in a singleton service and you can access that application ID in child component by injecting the service.

Comment: this is how I'm doing right now. But when  `applicationID` and `inputData `are present in case of edit, both condition are satisfied for `ngChanges` and `ngOnInit` respectively and multiple calls are made to fetch customer info. Before parent ngOnInit  can resolve `inputData`, child's ngOnInit is called and hence, the condition is failed.